# Dart throws LateInitializationError even when I initialize variables in initState

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm declaring two variables using the `late` keyword, so that I can initialize both of them in the `initState` function.

```
class _CustomNavBarState extends State<CustomNavBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AnimationController _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    Animation<double> _animation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0.8).animate(_animationController);
  }
//...
```

If `initState` gets called before any other function, why am I getting the following error?

> LateIinitializationError: Field '_animation@17200479' has not been initialized.

Here's some more code:

```
class CustomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomNavBar(
      {required this.icons,
      required this.names,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.activeIndex});
  final List<IconData> icons;
  final List<String> names;
  final Function(int) onPressed;
  final int activeIndex;

  @override
  _CustomNavBarState createState() => _CustomNavBarState();
}

class _CustomNavBarState extends State<CustomNavBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CustomNavBar oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.activeIndex != widget.activeIndex) {
      _animate();
    }
  }

  void _animate() {
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AnimationController _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    Animation<double> _animation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0.8).animate(_animationController);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 90,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [Theme.of(context).backgroundColor, Colors.black],
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      )),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          for (var i = 0; i < widget.icons.length; i++)
            TextButton(
                style:
                    TextButton.styleFrom(splashFactory: NoSplash.splashFactory),
                onPressed: () => widget.onPressed(i),
                child: ScaleTransition(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            widget.icons[i],
                            size: 30,
                            color: i == widget.activeIndex
                                ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                : Colors.white70,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            widget.names[i],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: i == widget.activeIndex
                                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                  : Colors.white70,
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                    scale: _animation))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove AnimationController and Animation<double> in initState(). You already defined them above.

Comment: In other words, the way you wrote those variables in the initializer, you are actually defining new local variables which "shadow" the instance variables you are trying to set. Thus the instance variables remain unset, causing the error you got. (I am flagging this question for closure because this is a beginner mistake basically amounting to a typo, and is unlikely to help future readers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is declaring a *local* variable:

```
AnimationController _animationController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

What you want is assign to your existing class member variable:

```
_animationController =
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```